# Switching back and forth between browser tabs when user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have a Product listing page that has an edit pencil that takes the user to the ProdDetail page in a new tab using window.open:

```
window.open('ProdDetail?ProdId=123', 'xyz');
```

Then from there the user can click a button which will open up a third tab of the ExtraProdDetails page.

```
window.open('ExtraProdDetails?ProdId=123', 'xyz');
```

Then finally from the ExtraProdDetails page a user can click a 'Back to Product Details' button which will switch tabs back to the ProductDetail page. Not opening up a new tab.

```
window.open('ProdDetail?ProdId=123', 'xyz')
```

The following flow above works perfectly and I end up with 3 tabs throughout the entire process.

Lets say I make a small change to the first step. When the user clicks the edit pencil I do not ProdDetail to be opened in a new tab anymore. I want it to navigate to ProdDetail within the same tab. To do this I simply change the following:

```
window.open('ProdDetail?ProdId=123', '_self');
```

Then when the user opens ExtraProdDetails I still want this to be in a new tab. Then finally when they click 'Back to Prod Detail' I expect it to take them to the original ProdDetail tab but instead it is creating a third tab. With this flow I only ever want it to be two tabs.

To recap here are the two flows:
**Flow 1:**

```
ProdListing (tab1) -> ProdDetail (new tab2) -> ExtraProdDetails (new tab3) -> ProdDetail (Goes back to existing ProdDetail tab2 like it should)
```

**Flow 2 - This flow does not have expected behavior:**

```
ProdListing (tab1) -> ProdDetail (tab1) -> ExtraProdDetails(tab2) -> ProdDetail (should be going to tab1, but is instead going to a new tab3)
```

Comment: Code running in one tab can only interact with another tab upon the creation of that tab (think parent > child). Child tabs can't control their parent.

Comment: @ScottMarcus So I guess this explains why a new tab initially has to be opened for all of this to work? I am still a bit confused. Can you elaborate on this? How come in my first example which is working: ProdListing -> ProdDetail (newTab1) -> ExtraProdDetail (newTab2) -> ProdDetail (existing tab1).

Comment: Well, what I'm saying is that this won't work because tab 3 can't refer to a tab that it didn't create. You are much better off with a single window that has sections that can be shown/hidden as needed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I updated the bottom of the post with the two separate flows. Can you explain how in flow 1 Tab3 is able to switch back to Tab2, but in the second flow it creates a new tab. My confusion is that in both cases ProdDetail opens a new tab to ExtraProdDetails. The only difference is how it all starts, in the first scenario a new tab is opened from the listing, in the second it is not. How in the world could this make or break why Tab 3 can return to Tab 2 or not. I made the bottom part of my post a lot more readable with tab numbers if you don't mind taking a look.